# How to convert and slice jpg to psd and keep layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, software-recommendation

**[MIGRATED FROM ASK UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436756/how-to-convert-and-slice-jpg-to-psd-and-keep-layers)**

I have several JPG designs of a website I'm developing. I did a pure HTML website and then did a full webpage screenshot for the design part. Now the client is asking for the PSD files, is there any way I can convert the JPG designs to PSD in GIMP or any other software?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and don't have a running copy of Photoshop.

**EDIT**
Is there any way I can slice up the JPG into the individual layers?

---

For confidentiality reasons, I can't upload the actual designs but here is a [sample](https://creativemarket.com/premiumcoding/8553-Elegantica-Website-PSD-Template) from [creative market](https://creativemarket.com/):

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused. Did you make the JPG yourself? If so, with what?

Comment: @JohnB I created the website with pure HTML(5) and CSS(3) and then screenshot the whole page using [screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/) a firefox addon.

Comment: Okay, that's what it sounded like. But why does the client need a .psd? Usually you take a PSD file and convert it to HTML/CSS, it feels like we're going backwards here

Comment: @JohnB Clients!! &*#^#*

Comment: LOL, I like the fact that you are reverse engineering the design so that you can provide a PSD. And by "like" I mean I empathize with your plight.

Comment: The thing is, you will not be able to take it back as a PSD file and work with it, so you ought to have a meeting about this. TIFF supports layers, and I (think) GIMP and (definitely) PS support TIFFS with layers, so you could transfer back and forth in this manner, but you would have to flatten layer effects AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

**Chances are the client is merely asking for what they *think* is used.** Some colleague or friend told them *"Make certain they give you the .psd."* So they ask for that. I would hesitate to state you needed to do so, especially for a website, if there is no .psd. A better course may be to explain *why* there is no .psd file and how much more versatility there is without it.

I get clients asking me for the ".psd" all the time, even for 56 page catalogs. They don't fully understand that other things *besides* Photoshop are used. I always take the opportunity to politely educate them a bit as to why I'm more than merely a Photoshop hobbyist and the breadth and scope of the tools in my toolbox :)

---

The only thing I know of...

For a Mac.

http://www.pagelayers.com/

> Page Layers is a website screenshot app for Mac OS X. It converts web pages to Photoshop files with separate layers for all page elements.
>
> Just open any page in the embedded browser and save the page as PSD with layers or as plain PNG image. Every web page element (every image, link, block, ...) will be rendered as separate, named layer. Layer groups will be created according to the site structure.

I have no idea if there's anything similar for Windows.

I am **not** affiliated with the link at all, just use the product when needed.

Comment: Thanks alot but I don't have a Mac. I use Ubuntu full time.

Answer (score 2):

What Scott said. You didn't start with a PSD, so there is no PSD to deliver and every reason not to go to extremes to create one. Explain to the client that the site was created directly in HTML.

If the project is complete, they don't require design files. If it isn't, I would definitely not deliver a Photoshop design file even if it existed. It's up to you if you want to provide Gimp files for individual elements you created and sized for the site; that's not usual practice in the design world unless it's stipulated in the contract before work begins.